# What is the best method for making database connection (static, abstract, per request, ...)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I used lot of model for connecting to db, in my last project that i worked with C# & entity framework, i created static class for db connecting but i had problem with opening and closing connection for that give me error when more than 10-15 requests come together, i solved it with changing method of connecting to db with i connect now per request and removed all static methods and classes.

Now i want to know,

**What is best model for making connection?**

1. Should i close it after every query and open it before using or ...?
2. A connection in static class is good model (that i don`t need to
   create it, every time)?
3. Is there a good design pattern for this problem?
4. All of it is for the same question What is the best method for
   making database connection (static, abstract, per request, ...)?

**For example** i working on a sms sender web panel, I should send 100K sms per second, these sms collect with others and make a package that every package have 1~20 sms then i need to send 5K~100K packages per one second and when i send a package i should do these steps:

1. Update single sms to delivered or not delivered
2. Update user balance if delivered decrease user balance in useraccounts table
3. Update number of sms send count in user table
4. Update number of sms send count in mobile number table
5. Update number of sms send count in sender number table
6. Update package for delivered and failed sms in package table
7. Update package for how thread send this package in package table
8. Update thread table for how many sms send it by this tread and how many failed
9. Add account document for this transactions in AccountDocument table

All steps and lot of other things like logs, user interface and monitoring widgets, that should doing and i need DB connection for doing every single of this transactions.

Now, What is best model for connecting to DB? By human request or by thread request or by every single transaction..

Comment: Look up **Unit Of Work** and the Repository patterns, good place to start.

Comment: It comes down to how you want to use transactions, as you generally want a new connection for each transaction (unless you can be sure transactions don't overlap). You don't want multiple connections per transaction as you then need to use distributed transactions which will hurt performance. If you're not thinking of this in terms of transactions you probably should be.

Comment: Option "2" is a definite no-no. Don't do that ever.

Comment: @Marc Gravell :D its good way but i can`t make money..!!

Comment: @Belogix tanx i try to read it but i cannot see how can i handle my connection in this way?

Comment: @James Gaunt thanks so much, i explain my project sizes and some problems in duffymo answer, please check it and help me, what should i do?

Comment: @Mehdi - the unit of work is the way to go. My point is don't think in terms of Request / Static / Instance / Thread.  Think Unit Of Work = Transaction.  Your database access pattern should not be tied to anything other that the unit of work / transactions you need to perform. This is the way to get the best performance and transactional safety. Google Unit Of Work, there are lots of code examples out there of various implementations.

Comment: for my English, if you find something wrong on question please edit it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh TBQH if you are handling that many requests per second, hire the best DBA that you can find who has worked on Amazon scale problems because this is a $1-2MM dollar question.

Comment: @Yaur it`s true but i try to find a good architecture for connecting to database independent hardware, database system & framework, i try to find some architecture for all of my projects and i think this project is good problem for connection architecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1. Should i close it after every query?`

.Net does that for you so let it handle it, that's a garbage collector task. So don't bother disposing your objects manually, this is a good answer by Jon Skeet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1998600/544283. However you could use the `using(IDisposable){ }` statement to force the GC to do it's work. Here is a nice article about resources reallocation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About.

`2. A connection in static class is good?`

**Never** make a data context static! Data contexts are **not** thread safe or concurrent safe.

`3. Is there a good design pattern for this problem?`

As Belogix mentioned dependency injection and unit of work patterns are great, in fact entity framework **is** a unit of work itself. DI and UoW are a bit overrated though, it's not easy to implement if it's your first time handling an IoC container which if you're going that path I'd recommend Ninject. One other thing is you don't really need DI if you're not gonna run tests, the awesomeness of these patterns is to decouple, so you can test and mock without sweat.

In-short: If you're gonna run test against your code go for these patterns. If not, I'm providing you an example about how you could share your data context among the services you'd like. This is the answer to your fourth question.

`4. What is the best method for making database connection (static, per request)?`

Your context service:

```
public class FooContextService {
    private readonly FooContext _ctx;

    public FooContext Context { get { return _ctx; } }

    public FooContextService() {
        _ctx = new FooContext();
    }
}
```

Other services:

```
public class UnicornService {
    private readonly FooContext _ctx;

    public UnicornService(FooContextService contextService) {
        if (contextService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contextService");

        _ctx = contextService.Context;
    }

    public ICollection<Unicorn> GetList() {
        return _ctx.Unicorns.ToList();
    }
}

public class DragonService {
    private readonly FooContext _ctx;

    public DragonService(FooContextService contextService) {
        if (contextService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contextService");

        _ctx = contextService.Context;
    }

    public ICollection<Dragon> GetList() {
        return _ctx.Dragons.ToList();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class FantasyController : Controller {
    private readonly FooContextService _contextService = new FooContextService();

    private readonly UnicornService _unicornService;
    private readonly DragonService _dragonService;

    public FantasyController() {
        _unicornService = new UnicornService(_contextService);
        _dragonService = new DragonService(_contextService);
    }

    // Controller actions
}
```

Second thoughts (almost an edit):
If you need your context not to create the proxies for your entities therefore not having lazy loading either, you could overload your context service as follows:

```
public class FooContextService {
    private readonly FooContext _ctx;

    public FooContext Context { get { return _ctx; } }

    public FooContextService() : this(true) { }

    public FooContextService(bool proxyCreationEnabled) {
        _ctx = new FooContext();
        _ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- If you set the proxy creation enabled to false you will **not** have lazy loading out of the box.
- If you have api controllers you **don't** want to deal with any full blown object graph.

EDIT:

Some reading first:

- This link relates to a pre-release version of EF6: [Entity Framework and Async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx).
- Scott Allen posted about this in his blog: [Async in Entity Framework 6.0](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/28/async-in-entity-framework-6-0.aspx).
- If you're going to use Unit of Work I'd recommend to read this: [Make the DbContext Ambient with UnitOfWorkScope](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/10/make-the-dbcontext-ambient-with-unitofworkscope/).
- [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744096/544283) on [Do asynchronous operations in ASP.NET MVC use a thread from ThreadPool on .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743067/do-asynchronous-operations-in-asp-net-mvc-use-a-thread-from-threadpool-on-net-4).

Get this done:

```
(_context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
```

This is a great article about [Managing Connections and Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx).

Entity framework exposes EntityConnection through the Connection property. Read as: `public sealed class EntityConnection : DbConnection`.

Considerations for managing connections: (taken from previous link)

- The object context will open the connection if it is not already open before an operation. If the object context opens the connection during an operation, it will always close the connection when the operation is complete.
- If you manually open the connection, the object context will not close it. Calling **Close** or **Dispose** will close the connection.
- If the object context creates the connection, the connection will always be disposed when the context is disposed.
- In a long-running object context, you must ensure that the context is disposed when it is no longer required.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What? "Don't bother disposing your objects manually" is bad advice. And "use the `using(IDisposable){ }` statement to force the GC to do it's work" is also inaccurate - the using statement doesn't force the GC to do anything.

Comment: @default.kramer: `"Don't bother disposing your objects manually"`: **Who does** dispose each object manually? Even if you manually dispose each object the GC won't do anything automatically, I was just saying that the GC is pretty smart about how and when to free resources. And `"use the using{} statement to force the GC to do it's work"`: Are you implying that a resource inside a `using` block doesn't call the `Dispose` method on that resource when it's scope is done? If so, why is a requirement to implement `IDisposable` when using a `using` statement? I'll change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Your first two sentences sound like "just leave your DB connections lying around, undisposed, and the GC will eventually take care of it." Maybe that's not what you mean. I think you misunderstand the relationship (or lack thereof) between the GC and `IDisposable`. A `using` block calls `Dispose`; the GC calls the Finalizer. A common "safety net" is to have the Finalizer ensure that `Dispose` was called, but in a well-behaved application this safety net should not be needed - all `IDisposables` should be disposed without any GC involvement.

Comment: Also I disagree with "you don't really need DI if you're not gonna run tests". Good OO design tends to favor DI (container-managed or not). I would describe the primary benefit as "composability" which leads to more maintainable applications. Testability is certainly a benefit, but it's more of a side effect of good design. I would not recommend "if you're going to write tests, do this, otherwise, do this."

Comment: @Esteban tanx a lot for helping me.i wondering about your answer, its really good and tanx again. i know about Disposable objects and garbage collector, but i think its not safe to let handle to close connection by garbage collector let me check example.. i had some linQ query and i try to find sms should be send from queue sms waiting table by a thread and thread should be update record status and load all of sms package and all of mobile numbers and calculate expense, when i used asynchronous calling methods, GC can not handle for close it. and all connection keep opened in same time.

Comment: @Esteban Please give me more describes about opening and closing connection in asynchronous calling methods when lot of threads (about 100~500 threads) worked with each other and every thread call lot of asynchronous methods!?

Answer (score 10):

answers to your questions:

1. Close it. .NET does connection pooling for you under the hood.
2. Create it. use the using (Connection conn = new ....) each time - this way, you'll make the most out of the .NET pooling mechanism.
3. you can use the .NET ThreadPool (or your own custom one), define the ThreadPool to use solely 10 thread in parallel and Enqueue work items one after another. this way no more then 10 connections will be used in the same time + it'll probably work faster. 
   More about Custom ThreadPools: [Custom ThreadPool Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31028/A-Custom-Thread-Pool-Implementation-Using-C)
4. Per instance.

---

Here's my suggestion for an architecture:

1. Create a database table (queue) for pending SMS to be sent out.
2. each row will contain all the information needed for the sms + the current status.
3. create a worker process, perhaps a windows service which will sample this table constantly - let's say, each 5 seconds. it will select the TOP ~20 SMS with status = 'pending to be sent' (should be represented as int). and will update the status to 'sending'
4. each sms will be sent out using a custom threadpool on the windows service side.
5. in the end of the process, ALL the processed sms status will be updated to 'done' using a CTE (common table expression - you can send a cte with all the sms rows ids that have just been process to do a 'bulk update' to 'done' status).
6. you could make the status update stored procedure to be the same one as the 'getpending'. this way, you could select-for-update with no lock and make the database work faster.
7. this way, you can have more than just one processor service running (but then you'll have to loose the nolock).

remember to avoid as much locking as possible.

by the way, this is also good because you could send SMS from any place in your system by simply adding a row to the pending SMS table.

And one more thing, i would not recommend to use entity framework for this, as it has too much going on under the hood. All you need for this kind of task is to simply call 3-4 stored procedures, and that's it. Maybe take a look at [Dapper-dot-NET](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) - its a very lightweight MicroDal framework which in most cases works more than 10 times faster than EF (Entity Framework)

Comment: Can you suggest me please, a good design pattern for working with custom theard pool?

Answer (score 5):

I think per request scales the best.  Use a thread-safe connection pool and make the connection scope coincide with the unit of work.  Let the service that's responsible for transactional behavior and units of work check out the connection, use it, and return it to the pool when the unit of work is either committed or rolled back.

UPDATE:

10-12 seconds to commit a status update?  You've done something else wrong.  Your question as written is not sufficient to provide a suitable answer.

[Daily NASDAQ volume](http://www.phlx.com/Trader.aspx?id=DailyMarketSummary) is 1.3B transactions, which on an 8 hour day works out to ~45K transactions per second.  Your volume is 2X that of NASDAQ.  If you're trying to do it with one machine, I'd say that NASDAQ is using more than one server.

I'd also wonder if you could do without that status being updated using ACID.  After all, [Starbucks doesn't use two-phase commit](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ramblings/18_starbucks.html).  Maybe a better solution would be to use a producer/consumer pattern with a blocking queue to update those statuses when you can after they're sent.

Comment: i had more problem in my project .. its a sms sender panel i send 100,000 sms per second and every single sms that i send it should be update status in db and i had 100 threads that worked together and i used async method for sending sms and in the other hand the users track sending sms.. now when i used per request my cpu performance go to high and i cannot send all of it in 1 second, its take 10-12 seconds. its no problem i upgrade my hardware, if i know the best way and secure one is connecting per request!

Comment: 10-12 seconds to commit not a single status update, for 100000 sending records that i want send 100000 in a second and i need more of nasdaq i want send 100K in a second and its only sending i update my mobile number table too & sender number & user sendingcount & thread that counting a single thread how much send sms and i decrease user balance and i create a account document transaction all of it for sending 1 sms and lot of other business ...

Comment: You sound overwrought and incoherent in these comments.  I don't think I can do much more for you.  Voting to close.

Comment: sorry i think its my English not my personality.. i change all of my class for connecting to db for 5 times and every time i read about it and i really like to find one is way is better and i should deliver project in next Saturday and i think, i had big problem in db connection. please introduce me a pattern for connecting to db.. i`m start reading about Unit Of Work, & Starbucks doesn't use two-phase commit, i think its good but i want find more patterns.

Comment: Are you doing this on a single server?  Have you profiled memory and CPU to see if the machine is capable of handling this load?  Is it load balanced?  Too many unknowns.  Your problems are greater than a simple question of patterns.

Comment: I do this project for a branch of MCI, hardware and other things is not my problem, i worked on it for 10 months till now, i want solve these problems on my PC (Core i7 with 8gb ram with 1Tb hard on windows 7), if i win then better hardware is better, and i set the lower things that needed is xxx, so i want to know that my way for connecting to db is good way or not? and for making money this company make ~100K$ per day..

Comment: You don't even know if it's the database connection time that's killing you.  Profile your app and use data instead of guessing.